# Need to add class dynamically to a <Button> in react bootstrap or just react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

here is my code in react and bootstrap:

```
    <ButtonGroup>
      <Button  value=1 onClick={this.props.filterMessages}>In</Button>
      <Button value=2 onClick={this.props.filterMessages}>Out</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
```

When the Button is clicked, I'd like to add a css class called `active=True` and `bsStyle="primary"`

```
function onClick(event) {
     /*add CSS class to my Button component, but how?*/
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with state of parent component.

```
function onClick(event) {
     this.setState({condition: true})
}

<Button  value=1 onClick={this.props.filterMessages} className={this.state.condition? "class" : "anotherClass"}>In</Button>
```

Create variable, that will keep condition of your button, and change it with some event. In button set className depend of your current value of variable.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have five classes already, and I only wish to add two more?  Is there a way to not have to repeat all five classes that I wish to keep?

Comment: Not sure i clearly understand you. Can you explain more?

Comment: Thanks I got it now, I explained it poorly and really had no question beyodn the one you answered.  Your solution really helped me!

Comment: You have something like className={"your five classes" + (this.state.condition? "class" : "anotherClass")} ?